# setInterval not working with callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the setInterval to call a function that will load orders using ajax. However when I pass in a argument to the call back,  the setInterval function stops working.   W

hen I don't pass in any arguments it starts working .

Any ideas on how I can make it work with arguments? Below is my code

Thank you in advance!

```
function httpGetRequest(page){
        $.get(page)
        .done(function(data){
              $(".display_orders").html(data);
        });
}
setInterval(httpGetRequest('load_orders.php'), 30000);
```

Comment: btw, this is likely a duplicate question, as newcomers often face this problem because they don't understand how javascript handles setting intervals and timeouts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case

```
setInterval (httpGetRequest('load_orders.php'), 30000);
```

the function executes immediately

Use like this

```
setInterval ( function() { 
     httpGetRequest('load_orders.php')
 }, 30000);
```

Comment: Or maybe like this `setInterval (httpGetRequest, 30000, 'load_orders.php');` (on modern browsers; IE > 9)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` be sure to give it a variable name so that you can cancel it if you need to.

```
var orderInterval = setInterval(function(){httpGetRequest('load_orders.php');}, 30000);
```

In the event that you want to stop it you are now able to call:

```
clearInterval(orderInterval);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use following syntax:

```
setInterval(httpGetRequest, 30000, 'load_orders.php');
```

Comment: fascinating, never knew you could pass parameters to the function after the milliseconds.

Answer (score -1):

Also you can call like this.

```
function myFunction()
{
httpGetRequest('load_orders.php');
}

function httpGetRequest(page){

        $.get(page)

            .done(function(data){
                $(".display_orders").html(data);
            });


}

setInterval (myFunction, 30000);
```